# "Ticker" for game timing

Tags: java, game, timer

I designed a "Ticker" based on how I imagine [Minecraft's tick system](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tick) works. My ticker calls a method `tickRate` times a second and provides a [Delta Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_timing) value (`deltaTime`) to the method being called.

The issue I have with my code is that I find the `update` method (which handles timing) to be ugly but I'm not sure what I can do.

My ticker class is designed to be instantiated and used whenever, it does not have to be used right away (which is why I don't set any time related information in the constructor). This is why there is a check for `nextTick` and `lastTick` being `0` inside `update`, as to ensure that the delta time does not go crazy on the first tick. The issue with this is that it looks a bit ugly, however I'm not sure what I could do. I *could* move the reset code into the `reset` method, however that would now mean that the `reset` method is time dependant, and must be only be called when you intend to use the ticker.

## `Ticker.java`

```java
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Ticker {
    private long lastTick;
    private long nextTick;
    private int tickRate;

    private Set<TickListener> tickListeners = new HashSet<>();

    public Ticker(int tickRate) {
        this.tickRate = tickRate;
    }

    public void addTickListener(TickListener listener) {
        tickListeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void removeTickListener(TickListener listener) {
        tickListeners.remove(listener);
    }

    public void setTickRate(int tickRate) {
        this.tickRate = tickRate;
    }

    public int getTickRate() {
        return tickRate;
    }

    public void reset() {
        lastTick = 0;
        nextTick = 0;
    }

    public boolean update() {
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        if (currentTime >= nextTick) {
            long targetTimeDelta = 1000L / tickRate;

            if (lastTick == 0 || nextTick == 0) {
                lastTick = currentTime - targetTimeDelta;
                nextTick = currentTime;
            }

            float deltaTime = (float) (currentTime - lastTick) / targetTimeDelta;

            for (TickListener listener : tickListeners) {
                listener.onTick(deltaTime);
            }

            lastTick = currentTime;
            nextTick = currentTime + targetTimeDelta;

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

## `TickListener.java`

```java
public interface TickListener {
    void onTick(float deltaTime);
}
```

### Example usage

```java
Ticker ticker = new Ticker(20); // 20 ticks per second

ticker.addTickListener(new TickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onTick(float deltaTime) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Ticked with deltaTime %f", deltaTime));
    }
});

while (true) {
    ticker.update();
}
```

Comment: Is `TickListener` a custom class? If so, I'm sure reviewers would appreciate having it so they could more easily understand your code. :)

Comment: `TickListener` is simply an interface with a method called `onTick`. I'll add it to the OP now.

Comment: You may want to consider http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351565/system-currenttimemillis-vs-system-nanotime

Comment: I would prefer to see you abstract `System.currentTimeMillis()` to some kind of external interface (for example, a `Clock` interface) - this would allow you to move backward and forward through time in unit tests without having to actually wait that many milliseconds?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one of the cleanest code I have come across in a while. Congrats to your lovely, well-written code!

Just some points:

1. I don't like seeing this:

   ```
   public class Ticker {
       private long lastTick;
       // ...
       }
   }
   ```

   It is more readable (IMO) when you put spaces after the beginning and before the end:

   ```
   public class Ticker {

       private long lastTick;
       // ...
       }

   }
   ```

   I don't see a reason why not to do so, as the rest of your code is very well spaced.
2. This method:

   ```
   public boolean update() {
       long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

       if (currentTime >= nextTick) {
           long targetTimeDelta = 1000L / tickRate;

           if (lastTick == 0 || nextTick == 0) {
               lastTick = currentTime - targetTimeDelta;
               nextTick = currentTime;
           }

           float deltaTime = (float) (currentTime - lastTick) / targetTimeDelta;

           for (TickListener listener : tickListeners) {
               listener.onTick(deltaTime);
           }

           lastTick = currentTime;
           nextTick = currentTime + targetTimeDelta;

           return true;
       }

       return false;
   }
   ```

   Just my opinion, but I feel uncomfortable with that many spaces in code. The only place I would use spaces would be:

   - Between `Node` declarations in JavaFX, or `JWhatever` declarations in Swing.
   - Where there is an obvious change in what the code will do.

   So it would be more like:

   ```
   public boolean update() {
       long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
       if (currentTime >= nextTick) {
           long targetTimeDelta = 1000L / tickRate;
           if (lastTick == 0 || nextTick == 0) {
               lastTick = currentTime - targetTimeDelta;
               nextTick = currentTime;
           }

           float deltaTime = (float) (currentTime - lastTick) / targetTimeDelta;
           for (TickListener listener : tickListeners) {
               listener.onTick(deltaTime);
           }

           lastTick = currentTime;
           nextTick = currentTime + targetTimeDelta;
           return true;
       }
       return false;
   }
   ```

Comment: For #2: You say to remove white space that shows that blocks of statements do related but not identical things… why?

Comment: I prefer the original layout.  It's a matter of taste, but it is certainly easier for _me_ to read.

Answer (score 6):

Your code is good, but if you care about any chance of multiple ticks per frame, you may want to use a `while` loop to keep ticking until you're up to speed. This is because `System.currentTimeMillis()` and `System.nanoTime()` are *'timers'*, rather than *'countdowns'* - they only measure time.

So, it's entirely possible something will go wrong or otherwise be slow and only one `update` will be called per 3 or 4 seconds, for example. This is where you could use a `while` loop:

```
public boolean update() {
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long targetDelta = 1000L / tickRate;
    ....

    boolean flag = false;
    while(currentTime >= lastTick + targetDelta) {
        for(TickListener listener : tickListeners) {
            listener.onTick(deltaTime);
        }
        lastTick += targetDelta;
        flag = true;
    }
    return flag;
}
```

I might also suggest using `nanoTime()` instead of `currentTimeMIllis()`, but this is up to you.

Comment: I designed the class to be non-blocking, so that you actually call the `update` method in a while loop. I should have added an example to my original post.

Answer (score -1):

An Example how I do it in my Projects when I need it, is that I use a new Thread and let it have handle the needed Stuff.

TickHandler.java

```
package me.donjoe.foo;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TickHandler extends Thread {

    private int tickRate = 60;
    private List<TickHandler> q = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            // Devide 1000 Millisecond (1 Second) through the tickrate
            // to get the time every tick has
            long timeout = 1000L / this.tickRate;
            // Buffer-Time which carries over the Time that the last tick took too long.
            // Used to make the Ticks in-sync again.
            long buffer = 0L;
            while (true) {
                // Check if Interrupted. If so, stop this Thread
                if (this.isInterrupted()) throw new InterruptedException();
                // Start Time
                long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                // TODO: Do some Stuff here
                // Handle the TickHandler / Callbacks
                for (TickHandler handler : this.q) handler.handle();
                // Maybe clear the Q, depends on how you like to work with it
                // this.q.clear();

                // Time to wait in this Tick
                long toWait = (timeout - buffer) - (System.currentTimeMillis() - start);

                // When the Time is negative, the Tick took too long to execute.
                // Set the buffer to the time it took too long and let is balance out.
                if (toWait < 0) buffer = -toWait;
                else {
                    this.wait(toWait);
                    // Clear the buffer. No time to wait on the next one
                    buffer = 0L;
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // The Thread got stopped. Do stuff here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue with this now is thread safety. If I do anything outside of the ticker thread, you can get race conditions which I'd rather avoid.